# Adding Autofac to WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, autofac

I can't seem to find an solution to this problem. I've seen several questions about this, but none really give me a solution. I am totally new to Autofac and haven't really done much WPF + MVVM, but know the basics.

I have a WPF application (using ModernUI for WPF) which I'm trying to add Autofac to, and I am having a hard time figuring out how to resolve my services within all the views, since they have no access to my container. I have a main view, which is my entry point, where I set up my container:

```
public partial class MainWindow : ModernWindow
{
    IContainer AppContainer;

    public MainWindow()
    {

        SetUpContainer();

        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = this; 
    }

    private void SetUpContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        BuildupContainer(builder);

        var container = builder.Build();

        AppContainer = container;
    }

    private void BuildupContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>();
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out how I can resolve my logger and other services within my other views, where I inject all my dependencies through the ViewModel constructor, like so:

```
public partial class ItemsView : UserControl
{
    private ItemsViewModel _vm;

    public ItemsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IFileHashHelper fileHashHelper = new MD5FileHashHelper();
        ILibraryLoader libraryLoader = new LibraryLoader(fileHashHelper);
        ILogger logger = new Logger();

        _vm = new ItemsViewModel(libraryLoader, logger);
        this.DataContext = _vm;
    }
}
```

Some views have a ridiculous amount of injected parameters, and this is where I want Autofac to come in and help me clean things up.

I was thinking of passing the container to the ViewModel and storing it as a property on my ViewModelBase class, but I've read that this would be an anti-pattern, and even then I don't know if that would automatically resolve my objects within the other ViewModels.

I managed to put together a simple Console Application using Autofac

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Cleaner>().As<ICleaner>();
        builder.RegisterType<Repository>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        var container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {

            ICleaner cleaner = container.Resolve<ICleaner>();
            cleaner.Update(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

but that was simple since it has a single entry point.

I'd like some ideas on how to add Autofac to my WPF app. I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I use Autofac for all my DI, here is an example I have with WPF\MVVM https://github.com/oriches/Simple.Wpf.DataGrid

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above:

I use Autofac with all my WPF MVVM applications, I believe it to be one of the better DI frameworks - this is my opinion, but I think it is valid.

Also for me PRISM should be avoided 99% of the time, it's a '*solution looking for a problem*' and since most people don't build dynamically composable runtime solutions in WPF it is not needed, i'm sure people would\will disagree.

Like any architectural patterns there is a setup\configuration phase to the application life-cycle, put simply in your case before the first View (window) is shown there will be a whole of setup done for Dependency Injection, Logging, Exception Handling, Dispatcher thread management, Themes etc.

I have several examples of using Autofac with WPF\MVVM, a couple are listed below, I would say look at the Simple.Wpf.Exceptions example:

https://github.com/oriches/Simple.Wpf.Exceptions

https://github.com/oriches/Simple.Wpf.DataGrid

https://github.com/oriches/Simple.MahApps.Template

Comment: this might be exactly what I'm looking for. From what I can see, you use the App OnStartup as your entry point and build your container from there. That seems easily doable for me. What I don't see clearly is how do you set up your scope from there? Where is your scope handled? I am referring to your Simple.Wpf.Exceptions  project.

Comment: Yes, everything starts in the OnStartup, setup exception handling, start up the bootstrapper (DI) and a lot of debug\diagnostic stuff

Comment: What do you mean by scope?

Comment: If you mean scope as in scope DI container,in general I don't use them, I have previously along time ago, but now I find if I'm diligent with the architecture and implementation (MVVM) then I don't in general need them. Having said that I did produce an example of how I might have scoped containers in an MVVM application, it's not been updated for along time so the nuget references are rather old - https://github.com/oriches/Simple.Wpf.Composition

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. I'll try these tonight and see how they work. I noticed in your Composition project how you control your scope in the App Start and Stop. That seems easier for me to follow. I'll try that one first.

Comment: I was thinking why I haven't recently want to be able to created scoped containers when doing WPF\MVVM, and the conclusion I came to was - if all the services in the application are registered as singletons because they are stateless and only the ViewModels are registered per-instance then I shouldn't need a scope because the services will be shared and the ViewModels shouldl be disposed of in a timely manner

Answer (score 12):

You can use a similar technique as your console application:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Cleaner>().As<ICleaner>();
        builder.RegisterType<Repository>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Add the MainWindowclass and later resolve
        build.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();

        var container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var main = scope.Resolve<MainWindow>();
            main.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to mark Main with `[STAThread]`. Then in the project's properties, under the Application tab, set the `Startup object` to the Program class.

However, I am not certain of the implications of not running `App.Run()` and of running `MainWindow.ShowDialog()` instead.

To do the same using `App.Run()`, do the following:

1) delete `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` from App.xaml

2) Add the following to App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Cleaner>().As<ICleaner>();
    builder.RegisterType<Repository>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    // Add the MainWindowclass and later resolve
    build.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();

    var container = builder.Build();

    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var window = scope.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you would assign the `container` to the `MainWindow` so that it'd be able to resolve more services or other windows if necessary?

Comment: @t3chb0t If you need other services in `MainWindow`, you would inject them in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

WPF doesn't have a natural composition root or easy DI integration. [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) is a pretty common set of libraries specifically intended to bridge that for you.

(That's not Autofac specific - it's general guidance for adding DI to WPF apps.)

Comment: I've read about Prism and have also read that it is quite an undertaking to apply it to an existing application (basically rewrite it), so I don't think this fits as my solution. I have a working application and it is fully DI, with unit tests, but I was hoping to use something like Autofac to clean up the injected paramaters.

Comment: Prism looks great thanks. @Ben - you might be surprised at how achievable the "rewrite" changes are if you already have DI and tests running. Working on a tested codebase in a way where you don't have to write new tests (refactoring) is much much faster than you might expect. It's a tragedy that people forget the "refactor" part of TDD red-green-refactor - it's also the fun part and the end results are a joy to maintain. Difficult if your team members aren't willing to learn frameworks though (so not practical in many contexts).