# How to access ProgressMessageHandler when creating HttpClient with IHttpClientFactory in WPF app?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Here I have `HttpClient` that reports back progress:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = true };
var ph = new ProgressMessageHandler(handler);

ph.HttpReceiveProgress += (_, args) =>
{
    //Do stuff that I would also like to do with the DI approach.
};

var client = new HttpClient(ph);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7145/");
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new(HttpMethod.Get, "DownloadFile");
requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _tokenConfig.AccessToken);
var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

This code works fine, I can read download progress,  but now I would like to remove `HttpClient` initialization from my class and instead inject `IHttpClientFactory` that nice folks at Microsoft have provided. So far I have found that I can configure it like this in my startup class:

```
services.AddTransient<ProgressMessageHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient("api", opt =>
{
    opt.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.GetValue<string>("HttpClientConfig:BaseUrl"));
})
.AddHttpMessageHandler<ProgressMessageHandler>()
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    return new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    };
});
```

and inject wherever I want. Now my question is how and where can I access `HttpReceiveProgress` now that I use the DI approach:

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("api");
```

instead of the first more traditional approach?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you manually created instances of [`HttpClientHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=net-7.0) and [`ProgressMessageHandler`]'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh995279(v=vs.118), and hooked up to the [`HttpReceiveProgress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh995181(v=vs.118)) event to handle progress reporting.

```bash
   +------------------------+        +---------------------+
   | HttpClientHandler      |        |  ProgressMessage    |
   | (AllowAutoRedirect)    |------->|  Handler(ph)        |
   +------------------------+        +----------+----------+
                                              |  HttpReceiveProgress Event
                                              v
                                       Your Event Handler
                                           (//Do stuff)
```

You are defining a named client "`api`" with specific configurations and a `ProgressMessageHandler` in your Startup class.
And you want to create a `HttpClient` instance using [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory) and access `HttpReceiveProgress` event from `ProgressMessageHandler`.

After reading ["Issues with the original HttpClient class available in .NET"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests), I see the notion of [Typed Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#typed-clients), which is essentially a class that accepts an `HttpClient` object (injected through its constructor) and uses it to interact with some remote HTTP service.

When you register and configure Typed Clients using `IHttpClientFactory`, you are setting up a more structured and manageable way to handle HTTP communications in your application. That approach also allows you to encapsulate any additional logic, such as progress reporting, within your Typed Client classes.

You might consider adapting the Typed Client pattern to encapsulate your `ProgressMessageHandler` logic.
For example, you could create a Typed Client class that accepts both an `HttpClient` and a custom progress handler.
That way, you can manage the progress reporting logic alongside the HTTP communication logic in a structured and DI-friendly manner.

Create first a custom progress handler class:

```cs
public class CustomProgressHandler : ProgressMessageHandler
{
    public CustomProgressHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler<HttpProgressEventArgs> ReceiveProgress
    {
        add { HttpReceiveProgress += value; }
        remove { HttpReceiveProgress -= value; }
    }
}
```

Then define a Typed Client class that accepts an `HttpClient` and `CustomProgressHandler` via constructor injection:

```cs
public class DownloadService : IDownloadService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly CustomProgressHandler _progressHandler;

    public DownloadService(HttpClient httpClient, CustomProgressHandler progressHandler)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _progressHandler = progressHandler;
        _progressHandler.ReceiveProgress += HandleProgress;
    }

    private void HandleProgress(object sender, HttpProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public async Task DownloadFileAsync()
    {
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new(HttpMethod.Get, "DownloadFile");
        // your code
        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    }
}

// In Startup.cs or Program.cs
services.AddTransient<CustomProgressHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<IDownloadService, DownloadService>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomProgressHandler>();
```

`CustomProgressHandler` encapsulates the `ProgressMessageHandler` logic.
`DownloadService` is a Typed Client that accepts an `HttpClient` and `CustomProgressHandler` via constructor injection.
You register `CustomProgressHandler` and `DownloadService` with `IHttpClientFactory`, linking `CustomProgressHandler` as a message handler.

---

Note: In the context of [Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/overview/?view=netdesktop-7.0), dependency injection (DI) is not integrated as seamlessly as it is in ASP.NET Core.
You would need to set up a DI container, like [Autofac](https://autofac.org/), as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43689124/6309), or [Unity](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/a-simple-example-of-using-dependency-injection-using-unity-in-wpf/), and then register and resolve dependencies. The core idea of creating a typed client and a custom progress handler remains applicable, but the registration and injection process may look different based on the DI framework you choose for your WPF application.

Using Autofac as the DI container (`Install-Package Autofac`):

Define your `CustomProgressHandler` and `DownloadService` classes as shown in the previous example, and set up your DI container in your WPF application:

```cs
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public IContainer Bootstrap()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register the custom progress handler
        builder.RegisterType<CustomProgressHandler>().AsSelf();

        // Register the typed client
        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var handler = c.Resolve<CustomProgressHandler>();
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7145/")
            };
            return new DownloadService(httpClient, handler);
        }).As<IDownloadService>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

In your WPF application's startup, initialize the DI container and resolve your typed client:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public App()
    {
        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        _container = bootstrapper.Bootstrap();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var downloadService = _container.Resolve<IDownloadService>();
        // your code
    }
}
```

That would give:

```bash
+-----------------------+         +-----------------------+
|    Bootstrapper       |         |       App             |
| (Dependency Setup)    |         | (WPF Application)     |
+-----------+-----------+         +-----------+-----------+
            |                                 |
            |                                 |
            | Register Dependencies           | Resolve Dependencies
            |                                 |
            v                                 v
+-----------------------+         +-----------------------+
|  Autofac Container    |         |  IDownloadService     |
|                       |-------->|  (DownloadService)    |
+-----------+-----------+         +-----------+-----------+
            |                                 |
            |                                 |
            |                                 | Uses
            v                                 v
+-----------------------+         +-----------------------+
| CustomProgressHandler |         |     HttpClient        |
|                       |<--------|                       |
+-----------------------+         +-----------------------+
            |
            | HttpReceiveProgress Event
            v
    Your Event Handler (HandleProgress)
    (// Do stuff)
```

The `Bootstrapper` class sets up dependency registration in the Autofac container.
The `App` class (WPF application) resolves `IDownloadService` which gets an instance of `DownloadService`.
`DownloadService` is the typed client that utilizes an `HttpClient` instance along with a `CustomProgressHandler` to handle HTTP requests and report progress.
`CustomProgressHandler` hooks up to the `HttpReceiveProgress` event to report progress, which is handled in your event handler method `HandleProgress`.

---

From [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77376245/how-to-access-progressmessagehandler-when-creating-httpclient-with-ihttpclientfa/77384937#comment136834814_77384937):

> I am struggling to make any use of ProgressMessageHandler at all.
>
> - First issue: it fires too often.
> - Second issue: it never knows progress or total size unless another message handler loads the response body. If so, the`ProgressMessageHandler` fires countless events of an already finished data transfer, and it then knows progress and total size (for what?).
>
> What do you think I might be doing wrong, or is it actually useless?
> I cannot find many examples of it being used in real-world apps.
>
> My goal is to create a centralized request/response progress tracker in-app using `.AddHttpClient()`"

The `ProgressMessageHandler` firing too often is usually due to the granularity of the progress reporting. That handler reports progress for every chunk of data received or sent, which can result in a high frequency of events, especially with large payloads or fast network connections.
You can try and implement logic in your event handler to process progress updates at a less frequent interval. That can be achieved by storing the timestamp of the last update and only processing new events if a certain amount of time has passed
Or, instead of processing each progress event individually, you can aggregate them and update the UI or your tracking mechanism at fixed intervals.

`ProgressMessageHandler` not knowing the progress or total size until the response body is loaded can be a limitation of how HTTP works. The total size of the response may not be known until the response headers are read, and sometimes not even then (if the `Content-Length` header is not set).
Make sure the server sends a `Content-Length` header. If you cannot rely on the `Content-Length` header, you might need to implement a custom mechanism for progress tracking. That could involve estimating progress based on average response sizes or other heuristics.

Creating a centralized tracker for request/response progress in a .NET application using `.AddHttpClient()` involves:

- A custom progress handler: instead of using `ProgressMessageHandler`, create a custom message handler that better fits your needs for progress reporting.
- An integration with HttpClientFactory: register this custom handler with `IHttpClientFactory` so it can be used with your HTTP clients.
- A progress reporting mechanism: implement a mechanism to report progress from your handler to a centralized system. That could be an event, a message bus, or another suitable pattern.

##### Create a custom progress handler:

```cs
public class CustomProgressHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Before sending the request, do something
        // 

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // After receiving the response, do something
        // 

        return response;
    }

    // Implement your progress reporting logic here
}
```

##### Register with HttpClientFactory:

```cs
services.AddTransient<CustomProgressHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient("myClient")
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomProgressHandler>();
```

##### Use in Application:

```cs
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public MyService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("myClient");
        // Use the client for HTTP operations
    }
}
```

In your `CustomProgressHandler`, you would implement the logic to determine when and how to report progress, potentially solving the issues you are facing with `ProgressMessageHandler`.

Comment: I am struggling to make any use of `ProgressMessageHandler` at all. 
First issue: it fires too often. Second issue: it never knows progress or total size unless another message handler loads the response body. If so, the ProgressMessageHandler fires countless events of an already finished data transfer and it then knows progress and total size (for what?).
What do you think I might be doing wrong or is it actually useless? I cannot find many examples of it being used in real world apps.
My goal is to create a centralized request/response progress tracker in app using  .AddHttpClient()

Comment: @user3625699 I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
The server is actually sending Content-Length it in my case but in HttpResponseMessage it can only be read from response.Content.Headers and these are only available after response is downloaded. That doesn't seem right. If the server sends Content-Length (of course it is not mandatory by HTTP RFC), it should be possible in C# to read it in DelegatingHandler. But I haven't found a way, do you know any for the current situation? I spent whole yesterday evening trying and I reported to github as well.
And 2. can request & response be uniquely identified when doing this?

Comment: @user3625699 It is better to ask a separate question (with a link back to this one). That way, we can focus on your issue there.

Comment: thank you but I am not able to create a new question because there is a warning that I would be blocked.